# Binding Array value in to listview control in nokia Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, nokia

In my application i have to bind a list of array value in to list view control.
so, I created like this and build successfully but it crash.

```
 QString array_List[5]={"Delphi","Mobile","Dot Net","Java","Open Source"};
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            list << array_List[i];
        }
    ui->list_View->setModel(new QStringListModel(list));
```

Comment: Where does it crash and what's the fault reported?

Comment: @stephen chu :when i go for this list view qwidget?

Comment: It's not a qt or nokia problem, it's purely a C++ one

Comment: What's `list`? Does it still crash after you've fixed the `i<=5` part? Also, you're leaking memory there with your `new QStringListModel`. You probably want something like `new QStringListModel(list, this)`. Or just use QListWidget, it's not like you're doing something useful with that model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your are going out of your array.

Replace

```
i<=5
```

with

```
i<5
```

I would prefer writing:

```
QStringList list;
list << "Delphi" << "Mobile" << "Dot Net" << "Java" << "Open Source";
ui->list_View->setModel(new QStringListModel(list));
```

Comment: your concept is working fine but I'm trying how to bind array values into list.

Comment: Each time you will update the model (here the list) the view will be updated. What's the problem with this?

Comment: "the model" and "the list" are very different things here. The model copies the list and doesn't care if you update it. If by "the list" you mean "the list inside the model", then you're correct, but that's not obvious from your wording, as "the list" sounds like it refers to the "list" variable.

Comment: @Sergey: Thanks to clarify this point. In my mind list refers to the "list inside the model"

Answer (score 1):

You need `i < 5` instead of `i <= 5`.